# alternative to cvPyrSegmentation

Tags: opencv, image-segmentation

i've tried cyPyrSegmentation to segment a image in different parts.

```
cvPyrSegmentation(in, out,storage, contours, level, 80, 20);
```

the segmentation of the output is very good. So in my continued process i want to work with the position of the different segments. But now i notice that `cvPyrSegmentation` only save the rectangle coordinates and not the whole pixels from segments :/. But the rectangle is too unexact.

Does someone have an idea?

greeting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,
now i've implemented a very fast segmentator which based on a weighted union graph([Effcient Graph-Based Image Segmentation](https://cs.brown.edu/people/pfelzens/papers/seg-ijcv.pdf)). The results look awesome i think.

[image: Image Hosted by ImageShack.us]